# Neural network design 2nd edition solution manual

Tags: neural-network

Is there a solution manual for the book below 
http://hagan.okstate.edu/nnd.html

I am solving the exercises from each chapter and I am having trouble identifying if I am making any mistakes.

Complete solution is not required as long as I have the final answer so I can verify my solution.

Answer (score 3):

**I have created a Solution Manual, icluding code solutions too, which you can find in [this Github repo.](https://github.com/estamos/Neural-Network-Design-Solutions-Manual)** A solution manual by authors does not exist.

In addition,  in case you need help with an exercise of the book or in general if you have a question about Neural Networks you can have a look at [**Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange**](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), which is the best community to learn and discuss. You are also encouraged to use [**discussions**](https://github.com/estamos/Neural-Network-Design-Solutions-Manual/discussions) section of the repo, for questions related to book exercises and examples.

As a last resort, there are many sites like Chegg Study, CourseHero where you can pay to get solutions but I wouldn't recommend it at all . Also, you can search on internet the description of the problem you are studying, since a lot of universities & polytechnic schools are using this book.

In the repo are also included written solutions and explanations by multiple contributors.